# ROBOCOPY - Getting File System Type of Destination - Access is denied

Tags: robocopy

I am trying to run a copy command to transfer a Zip file from the local file system to a UNC path on a different server. The file does copy but I get the below error and exit code 1. The user has full permissions on the destination folder.

Command:

```
robocopy "C:\vsts-agent\_work\1\a\" "\\file-clstr\websites\" "Global.zip"
```

Output:

---

### ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows

Started : 12 December 2017 13:36:46
2017/12/12 13:36:46 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Getting File System Type of Destination \file-clstr\websites\
Access is denied.
   Source : C:\vsts-agent_work\1\a\
     Dest - \file-clstr\websites\
    Files : Global.zip

### Options : /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

```
                   1    C:\vsts-agent\_work\1\a\
    New File         375.3 m    Global.zip
```

0.0%
  0.2%
  0.5%
  0.7%
  1.0%
  1.3%
  1.5%
  1.8%
  ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had checked folder permissions but not the share permissions. This is what was giving the error.

Comment: Had the exact same issue, we also forgot to check the share permissions. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this in case it helps anyone else...
I too experienced Access Denied error with robocopy command.  I verified the folder+share permissions.

What it ended up being is the user account that the source computer was running for the robocopy call was 'Local System' rather than a domain or shared local account. This built in account cannot used for network access.  The user running the service could not be changed so what I ended up doing is placing the robocopy call in a batch script along with `net use` to map the share with appropriate account.

Comment: Same for me, just added this to my batch file:  NET USE Z:\  \\myserver\sharefolder